# Android 7 изменение системной даты и времени програмно

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, root

Возникла необходимость программного изменения времени и даты в системе. Аndroid. Как я понял, доступ к `setTime` перекрыт на уровне ядра.

Как это можно обойти?

Приложение для личных нужд. Гуглинг рабочего ответа не дал.

Comment: плохо гуглили - в первой же строчке гугла: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939572/how-to-set-time-to-device-programmatically

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ. Видимо Вы правы

Answer (score 0):

у меня вот так заработало.

```
String s = time.format("%Y%m%d.%H%M%S");
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes("date -s " + s + ";");
os.flush();
os.close();
```

в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>
```

но хочет рут-права.
Как без рута - не нашёл.